# How many bit strings of length n contain more 0’s than 1’s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, bit-strings

To solve this, I think we need to use combinatorial reasoning.=

Consider a bit string of length ( n ). There are ( 2^n ) possible bit strings of this length because each bit can independently be either 0 or 1.

Let's denote:

- ( k ) as the number of 0's in the string
- ( n ) as the length of the bit string

This means:

- For ( k = 0 ), there's only one possibility, which is all bits being 1. So, there's 1 string.
- For ( k = 1 ), there are ( n ) possibilities because there are ( n ) positions where the single 0 can be placed in the string.
- For ( k = 1 ), there are ( \binom{n}{1} ) possibilities because there are ( n ) positions where the single 0 can be placed in the string.
- For ( k = 2 ), there are `\( \binom{n}{2} \)` possibilities because we're choosing 2 positions out of ( n ) for the 0's to occupy.
  -For  ( k = 3 ), there are ( \binom{n}{3} ) possibilities, and so on, until ( k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor )

The asnwer: total number of bit strings with more 0's than 1's is the sum of the possibilities for each ( k ) from 0 to ( \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor ).

Is this right?

Comment: You can come up with a much cleaner and easier final answer than this.  When $n$ is odd... how many do you think there are more of?  Those with more zeroes than ones?  Or those with more ones than zeroes?  How about when $n$ is even?  How does that change the answer?